# Stress-energy tensor components for a perfect fluid

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The stress-energy tensor for a perfect fluid is given by $$T_{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)U_{\mu}U_{\nu}-pg_{\mu\nu}$$ where U is the 4-velocity. The matrix components of the SEM are written as $$T_{\mu\nu}=diag(\rho,p,p,p).$$  Will this always be the components of the stress energy tensor despite having different components for the metric in each case or do they change according to the formula?

Comment: Hello! I do not understand the second equation: do not mix index notation and matrix one, it can lead to misleading ideas. For example: T00 is rho, ok.. but in which frame? What you wrote is valid only in the local rest frame of the local fluid element.

Comment: The first equation is valid in any frame correct? or is it just the MCRF

Comment: You cannot identify any arbitrary stress energy tensor with stress energy tensor for an ideal fluid. For instance, you cannot explain the inhomogeneities in general fluids (like shear, vorticity, divergence)using only perfect fluid stress energy tensor. Check this article : https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9812046v5

Comment: @KP99 Thank you for the article link . It cleared up some misconceptions I had regarding the SEM tensor. Is it true that the perfect fluid definition only holds in the MCRF, or can there still be a perfect fluid where it has different 4-velocity components?

Comment: If there are different 4-velocity components , then it will correspond to a tilted fluid stress energy tensor. It won't be a perfect fluid anymore, since the velocity of the fluid is not aligned with velocity of observer, and it will give rise to inhomogeneities

Comment: That makes sense. Suppose we have a metric $ds^2=-e^{2 \phi}dt^2+\left(1-\frac{b}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d \Omega^2$. If we want to do find for example the $T_{11}$ component for this metric, would it just be $$pg_{rr}=p\left(1-\frac{b}{r}\right)?$$ Or despite the elements of the metric, will the stress energy tensor for a perfect fluid always be $T_{\mu\nu}=diag(\rho,p,p,p)$? And is it true that the 4-velocity components for the perfect fluid follow as $U=(1,0,0,0)$?

Comment: It will be a good exercise if you try it yourself. Check whether you can write the stress energy tensor components as a diagonal matrix (like the perfect fluid). Or you can also use the general fluid stress energy tensor in the attached article and see whether you get any non trivial component for this metric. Just equate the Einstein tensor with general fluid stress energy tensor and calculate the components

Comment: It's a tensor like you said yourself. The components transform as those of a tensor.

Comment: The first expression is valid in any reference frame, the second one in the reference frame in which u=(1000), namely the local frame comoving with the local fluid element.

Comment: Moreover, just to be extra clear: "being a perfect fluid" is a property of matter, independent from the observer (like, say, "being solid"). A perfect fluid is a perfect fluid in any reference frame. The first T is the T of a perfect fluid in any reference frame, the second one is the special case when you are in the particular frame of the fluid itself.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411934/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63360/226902

Answer (score 3):

Consider your stress-energy tensor:
$$
T_{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)U_{\mu}U_{\nu}-p g_{\mu\nu}
$$
This is a legit tensor written in terms of other tensors (the scalar fields $\rho$ and $p$, the metric and the velocity field): the RHS is the *constitutive relation* for $T_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of your *macroscopic* fields ($U_{\mu}$, $\rho$...). You can use more complex constitutive relations (possibly involving more macroscopic fields) for dissipative fluids, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365940/226902) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/180979/226902) questions and links [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730551/226902).

Note that  $\rho$ and $p$ are scalars *by construction*, because are the physical properties of the matter in the local reference frame comoving with the local matter element (more precisely: this is the rest frame defined by the *conserved* current in your system, whatever it is, typically the [baryon current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number)).

If you want the energy in the local comoving reference frame, you just have to calculate $T_{\mu\nu} U^\mu U^\nu$.

This representation of $T_{\mu\nu}$ is tensorial, meaning that it's always valid (for any spacetime and fluid configuration). The second representation that you're proposing is valid only in the reference frame of the fluid (aka, a frame that is instantaneously comoving with a local fluid element). Locally, in this frame, the velocity is represented by $U^\mu \sim (1,0,0,0)$. Therefore, $T^{00}= \rho$, and so on... (you find the diagonal matrix representation). Again, this is valid for every metric, but in a specific ["tetrad"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism) of the fluid element.

See also: [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fluid), [Stress-energy tensor for a perfect fluid in GR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411934/226902), [Stress-energy tensor. Why this general form?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81334/226902), [What is a "perfect fluid", really?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528144/226902).